# how do I uninstall Ubuntu server and install Ubuntu desktop?

Tags: usb-installation

I installed a Ubuntu server, not knowing that it didn’t come with a GUI, and since I don’t have Ethernet connection, upgrading it with a sudo command is not an option. how would I go about uninstalling Ubuntu server, and installing Ubuntu desktop with my USB? It already has the installation loaded onto it.

Another option that might work for me is to install an Ubuntu Desktop Environment (GUI) on Ubuntu Server, but how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Is this a dual boot with Windows? Do you have any data (photos, music etc) in this computer? If not, just create a new USB with Ubuntu desktop and install again into your internal drive erasing everything in the disk.

Comment: You don't uninstall an OS, you just install over it. As you appear to realize, if you have internet you can add the desktop to your existing system (*you didn't provide release or product details so this advice is generic*) assuming you don't have a Ubuntu Core server install, or just re-install Ubuntu Desktop over it. The installation media doesn't contain packages but a full installation that is installed.

Comment: This does not look like a duplicate to me. I vote to keep open.

Comment: See if this is what you want: https://itsfoss.com/install-gui-ubuntu-server/ You can use Synaptic (on a computer with Internet), to make an installer for Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Please follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). You need a computer with an internet connection and a USB flash drive.  It doesn't matter what's currently on the computer, you'll be overwriting it.

Comment: Here is the **Official Tutorial** for installing Ubuntu apps offline, including the Ubuntu Desktop GUI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Synaptic/Offline However I think that the itsfoss tutorial is a little easier to follow.

Comment: FYI: If you've got files on your system, you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop without format which makes it non-destructive, ie. user settings remain, and *manually installed* packages (if from Ubuntu repositories) get re-installed automatically, thus allowing you to re-install without loss of data (unless data is within system directories; do NOTE many server apps store data in system directories which get erased prior to re-install, desktop apps don't do this). I do this 45+ times per year on *development* releases which currently includes *jammy*/22.04.2 media instead of updating as part of QA